# Folder in use, although it isn't

Tags: windows, file-permissions, file-management

Environment:

- Windows 11
- NAS - TrueNAS CORE on FreeBSD/amd64

I am trying to rename a folder. A few minutes ago I opened a file from this folder but now everything is closed.

I get the message:

```
Folder In Use
The action can't be completed because the folder or a file in it is open in another program
Close the folder or file and try again.
```

After waiting a few minutes, I am able to rename the folder.

It seems like Windows (or TrueNAS?) needs time to clear a lock. Is there a way to fix this behavior?

Comment: You will identity what process holds the file lock. My guess it’s Copilot since your running Windows 11

Comment: How can I identify the process that holds the lock to a specific file or folder?

Comment: [Here is a related question that might be helpful](https://superuser.com/questions/324399/windows-explorer-keeps-handle-open-on-executable-files?rq=1). You can also verify Copilot Preview isn’t turned on